# Count number of entries based on date posted, returns weird message

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce, razor, webmatrix

I want to check if an entry has been made already for a certain date.

I've tried a few variations on the below (*, etc) but it always returns the same message, and I have no idea what it means.

Query:

```
 @{
    var TodayDate = DateTime.Now;
    var TheUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

    var db= Database.Open("StarterSite");
   var sqlQ = "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Days WHERE EntryDate = @0 AND UserId =@1";
   var data = db.Query(sqlQ, TodayDate, TheUser);
}
```

The result of which is:

"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]"

It's the same whether or not there is a result in the table (i.e. not NULL)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I'm hoping to get a result - (either 1 or NULL) so I can then set a message if the user has posted content for that day or not.

Many thanks.

Comment: how are you actually printing out the `data` variable?

Comment: For the moment I'm just printing it like this: <h3>@data</h3> to test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
var count = db.QueryValue(sqlQ, TodayDate, TheUser);
```

Notice the use of `QueryValue()` instead of `Query()`.

Comment: Thank you, that's worked. It's returning 0 but I've realised that's because I'm including the time in the date posted, so I will just have to work out how to extract the date only and ignore the time and that should do it. Many thanks.